# A mysql order by usage ？

Tags: mysql

```
order by `order`=0，`order`
```

What dose it mean?
It's unusual,usually we use

```
order by `order` asc
```

,isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will cause all rows with `order` equal to zero to be sorted first, follow by rows with `order` non-zero, in numerical order. If order is always greater or equal to zero, this will be the same as sorting by order, however, if `order` can be negative, it will have an effect.

Consider the following data:

```
Order | ID
======|===
0     | A
10    | B
5     | C
-5    | D
```

Sorting by `order` will give you:

```
Order | ID
======|===
-5    | D
0     | A
5     | C
10    | B
```

While sorting by `order=0，order` will give you:

```
Order | ID
======|===
0     | A
-5    | D
5     | C
10    | B
```

Note that the row with `ID` of A is at the start, where previously it was second.

Answer (score 1):

This sorts by two values.

The first value (to sort by) is `order = 0`, which is `1` if `order` is `0` and `0` otherwise (`=` is the normal comparison operator).

If that value is the same for two rows, it will then sort by the `order` field itself.